# CSS should only apply if font family is not $fontFamily-special

Tags: css, sass

I have the following SCSS rule

```
strong,
b {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: $fontFamily-brand-heavy;
}
```

I want to add a conditional so that the style should only apply when the font-family is not `$fontFamily-special`

Is this possible to do with SCSS?

Answer (score 0):

You can search for conditional queries in SCSS. You can use conditional statements like this (just an example to explain)

```
@mixin bp($point) {

$bp-babybear: "(font-family: $fontFamily-special)";

@if $point == baby-bear {
   @media #{$bp-babybear} { //your condition }
}

}
```

Comment: I don't understand how this applies to my problem. Can you express it in terms of my problem instead of babybear? I can use @if to test a variable, but how do I get font of the element into that variable?

Comment: thought i have given you idea of using if else in this and rest you'll figure out yourself